# Magento Search Friendly URLs not working

Tags: magento2, url, seo

I changed the config/web/seo/server rewrites to YES. However my urls are still showing `/catalog/category/view/s/electric/id/911/`

Comment: have you enabled modrewrite and restarted the server (if apache)?

Comment: and did you reindex the url_rewrite index and clear the cache afterwards?

Comment: How do you reindex the url_rewrite index? Its not an option in the admin reindex and its not coming up when I run magento indexer:reindex

Comment: any news about how to run reindex for url?